# Angular 7 - ControlValueAccessor - Trim input values that are binded to a form

Tags: angular, angular7, controlvalueaccessor

We have a input field on a web page that must be trimmed at the same time as the user enter that data. As the input is binded to an Angular Form the value in the Form must also be trimmed.
I use Angular 7

```js
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  forwardRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  Renderer2
} from "@angular/core";
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR
} from "@angular/forms";


@Directive({
  selector: "[ebppInputTextTrimmer]",
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => InputTextTrimmerDirective),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class InputTextTrimmerDirective implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() prevVal: string;

  @Input() isTrimEnabled: boolean;

  onChange = (_: any) => {
  }

  onTouched = () => {
  }

  constructor(
      private _renderer: Renderer2,
      private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    const normalizedValue = value == null ? "" : value;
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "value", normalizedValue);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "disabled", isDisabled);
  }

  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  handleInput(inputValue: any): void {
    let valueToProcess = inputValue;
    if (this.isTrimEnabled) {
      valueToProcess = inputValue.trim();
    }

    this.onChange(valueToProcess);
    // set the value that is trimmed in the view
    this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "value", valueToProcess);
  }

}
```

The code shown works fine for me. I wonder if there a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a custom value accessor like below as a directive:

```
const TRIM_VAL_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => TrimValAccessor), multi: true});

@Directive({
  selector: 'input[trimval]',
  host: { '(keyup)': 'valOnChange($event.target)' },
  providers: [ TRIM_VAL_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class TrimValAccessor extends DefaultValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {
  }

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      super.writeValue(value.toString().trim());
    }
  }

  valOnChange(el) {
    let val = el.value.trim();
    this.renderer.setElementProperty(el, 'value', val);
    this.onChange(val);
  }
}
```

give referece in module:

```
declarations: [ TrimValAccessor ]
```

or in component like this

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <input type="text" trimval/>
  `,
  directives: [ TrimValAccessor ]
})
```

use in input tag to trim the value

```
<input type="text" trimval/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your implementation to

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[ebppInputTextTrimmer]"
})

export class InputTextTrimmerDirective {
  @Input("ebppInputTextTrimmer") isTrimEnabled = false;
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
      private _renderer: Renderer2,
      private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
  handleInput(inputValue: any): void {
    if (this.isTrimEnabled) {
      const valueToProcess = inputValue.trim();
      this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, "value", valueToProcess);
      this.ngModelChange.emit(valueToProcess);
    }
  }

}
```

and add it conditionally to the template by using

```
<input
[(ngModel)]="filter[columnConfig.key]"
...
[ebppInputTextTrimmer]="isAutoTrim(columnConfig)"
...
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried solving this issue by listening to `control.valueChnages` observable in the parent form and trimming and setting value there.

Have a method in your control value accessor class, Register it as onChange method.

```
onChange () {};

registerOnChange(fn) {
  this.onChange = fn
}
```

Have your input box like:

```
<input type="text" [value]="value" (input)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

In the parent component where you have defined the form.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.parentForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    age: new FormControl(12)
  })

  this.valueChangesSub = this.parentForm.get('age').valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(50),
    switchMap(newVal => of(newVal))
  ).subscribe((newVal) => {
    this.parentForm.get('age').setValue(newVal, {emitEvent: false});
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
    this.parentForm.get('age').setValue(newVal.trim(), {emitEvent: false});
  })
}
```

Assuming, `age` is the form control of for the control value accessor class. You will notice that I am setting the value twice, this is to let angular work with change detection and update your input view whenever trim is done.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ulyju7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: thanks. i guess that would work too. i forgot to write that we have a pretty generic data structure. we add the data to the from programmatically. so this solution would not fit for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you using `Reactive Forms`, you can `valueChanges` to subscribe for values then trim it manually and patch the values again.

A complete example would be:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  trimSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit(): void {


    this.trimSubscription = this.materialForm.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
      )
      .subscribe((formValues) => {

        let trimmedValues = Object
          .keys(formValues)
          .reduce((previous, currentKey) => ({
            ...previous,
            [currentKey]: typeof formValues[currentKey] == 'string' ? formValues[currentKey].trim() : formValues[currentKey],
          })
            , {});

        this.materialForm.patchValue(trimmedValues);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.trimSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  materialForm = new FormGroup({
    desc: new FormControl(''),
    descAr: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    nameAr: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    price: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.min(0)]),
    categoryId: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure Angular way, but sometimes it looks more effective. Call it on the submit event. And it uses the lo-dash to trim (the IE is still here yet).

```
trimInputs() {
    const cssSelector = 'input[type="text"]:not(.no-trim), textarea:not(.no-trim)';
    const inputs: (HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement)[] = this.el.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(cssSelector) || [];
    inputs.forEach((input) => {
        if (_.isString(input.value)) {
            input.value = _.trim(input.value);
            input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        }
    })
}
```